# Super basic firestore security rule won't work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't get the literal simplest firestore security rule I can write to work in the play ground. Just for testing, I've made a Cloud Firestore database with a collection named `users`. It has one field `stuff`. In the playground, these are my rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm simulating a get on location: `/databases/(default)/documents/users`, but it always fails due to the `document=**` match, and never matches `/users/{user}`. Why is this! Feels like I'm following the most basic examples from the docs.

Added a couple screenshots for clarify.

[image: Firestore]

[image: Rules Playground. Note that the location is <code>/databases/(default)/documents/users</code>]

Comment: Please edit the question to show more clearly what you're trying that doesn't work.  I suggest adding a screenshot of the console to show the specifics, so that anyone can match it and reproduce it.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I added a couple screenshots. Should make it 100% explicit what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Rules playground", in the location field, you don't need to enter `/databases/(default)/documents/`. This part of the path is already taken into account, as it is shown above the editable field with the pale grey (or greyed out) `/databases/(default)/documents` string.

So, by just entering `users/C8YDk...` it will work, since your rule allows reading the doc, due to an [overlapping matching statement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements).

More info on how to use the playground is to be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator#use_the).

Comment: Yup, that's all it was. I knew it had to be something small like that.